# loop through list and perform calculations on each unique value in excel VBA

Tags: excel, loops, subset, vba

I have some excel data:

```
apple   7.00    30/05/2017
apple   3.00    05/05/2017
apple   3.00    11/05/2017
apple   7.00    12/05/2017
apple   7.00    16/05/2017
apple   7.00    17/05/2017
banana  7.00    18/05/2017
orange  7.00    19/05/2017
orange  7.00    22/05/2017
orange  7.00    23/05/2017
orange  7.00    24/05/2017
orange  7.00    25/05/2017
orange  7.00    26/05/2017
orange  7.00    05/06/2017
orange  7.00    06/06/2017
orange  7.00    08/06/2017
orange  7.00    09/06/2017
orange  7.00    12/06/2017
```

And would like to cycle through each entry and perform some calculations. I am new and trying to learn VBA, and in R would do the following:

```
df=NULL
for(i in unique(col1)){
    a=subset of data
    perform some calculation of the data a
    append results to a df
}
```

My question is, how can I do this in VBA

in the above section, the result I am interested in is:

```
fruit   number of 5d weeks at same price
apple   0 
banana  0
orange  1
```

My data is ~10k rows

Comment: Did you even read about [For Loops](http://www.excel-easy.com/vba/loop.html) in VBA?

Comment: that's the page I was looking at before posting here actually

Comment: If you post the VBA code you've actually and tell us what is not working, you'll get much more response. Not many people will write the entire code for you based on psuedo-code from another language.